# Undocumented planning_environment parameters

Tags: ros, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2's [environment server launch file](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_arm_navigation/trunk/pr2_arm_navigation_actions/launch/environment_server.launch) sets some parameters that are undocumented in the [planning_environment package wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment), in particular:

- object_padd
- pointcloud_padd
- joint_state_cache_allowed_difference

Of these, the first two appear in the [API docs of the package](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/planning_environment/html/). My intention is to edit the wiki and document them. My question is mostly concerned with the third (undocumented?) parameter. Does it refer to the maximum allowed (past/future) extrapolation time when querying the joint states cache?.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10213/undocumented-planning_environment-parameters/) by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-06-28**:
Yes, it does refer to the maximum allowed past/future time. It won't really extrapolate, it will just use the joint states at the cache limits if the timestamps are outside the cache timestamp limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Added undocumented parameters to the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/planning_environment) and submitted a trivial [doc patch](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5034).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0